# Python TKINTER. Getting the returned value to Button(command)

Tags: python, function, tkinter, command, parameter-passing

```
def input_user_choice(array):
    Lb1=Listbox(top2, bg="Grey", height=16, relief=RAISED)
    for i in range(len(array)):
        Lb1.insert(i,array[i])
    Lb1.place(x=100,y=150)

    def getSelection(Lb1):
        values=Lb1.curselection()
        if values:
             index=values[0]
             value=Lb1.get(index)
             return(value)

    choice=""
    button=Button(top2,text="Guess!", command = lambda : choice==getSelection(Lb1),bg="Green")
    button.place(x=100,y=450)
    print(choice)
```

---

Hello everyone!

I've been coding a simple UI for my game and I've been stuck here for a week. I've set up a "Guess" button, which in command calls the function getSelection(). The variable value returns the selection. I'm having trouble receiving this value in the variable choice outside the function.
Your help will mean a lot.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You cannot get a returned value from a button callback, store it to a variable and make it global or store it in a list or so.

Comment: Change `choice` to `StringVar()` and update it inside `getSelection()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Do you mean using .get() function to update?

Comment: I tried implementing the global variable technique. It's not working.

Comment: Use `.set()` to update a `StringVar`.

Comment: It's not working. I tried everything from StringVar to .set().

Comment: What do you mean *"It's not working"*?  Update your question with the changes so far.